# Trigger event when asp textbox's text is changed

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I have a asp:TextBox which is binded to calender. I want to update gridview when date is changed via calender. How can i do it without submitting the form?

Comment: We would need more details to better understand the situation, but when updating your gridview, will the data come from the server ? in this case you will have a postback anyway. Or do you intend to update the gridview with client-side logic ?

Comment: yes..gridview data come from server... but i want to do that with textchanged event of asp:textbox...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle the calendar's SelectionChanged event, and from there call the textbox's textChanged event which would in turn update the gridview, like so:

```
protected void MyCalendar_SelectionChanged(object obj, EventArgs e)
{
    MyTextbox.Text = MyCalendar.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
    TextBox_TextChanged(null, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```